# Will linux readlink() syscall touch block device it refers to?

Tags: linux, posix, system-calls, readlink

I have a question regarding linux (or POSIX) readlink syscall.
Will linux implementation of readlink() touch block device contained in "link" or will it only do IO on block device hosting the filesystem containing the link inode?